# What is the correct way to upload/stream a large base64 string to Mvc from javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to send a large base64 string (multi-megabyte) from a javascript client to our Mvc server.  Currently we're using Ajax and sending the string like this:

```
Upload = function (aUrl, aFormData, aOnProgress, aOnSuccess, aOnTimeout, aOnError) {
   var settings = {
      url: aUrl,
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: JSON.stringify(aFormData), // { aData: longBase64String }
      success: function (resultObject, textStatus) {
         if (textStatus == "success" && aOnSuccess) aOnSuccess(resultObject);
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         if (textStatus == "timeout" && aOnTimeout) aOnTimeout();
         else if (textStatus == "error" && aOnError) aOnError();
      }
   };

   settings.xhr = function () {
      var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create xml http request.
      if (req) req.addEventListener('progress', aOnProgress, false); // Upload progress.
      return req;
   }

   return $.ajax(settings);
}
```

The aFormData is simply taking a Json object with the base64 string in it: `{ aData: myString }`.

On the Mvc side, we have this code for the controller:

```
[Authorize, RequireHttp, HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetImage(String aData) {
   // Do something with the data.
   return Json("We got it.");
}
```

Now - as far as getting the data to the server, this seems to be working in our localhost test environment.  I am concerned though that this may not be "streaming" in a nice asynchronous and buffered manner, but instead might block everything until it is sent, and I'm not seeing the "real" impact on the client since it is running localhost.  I just don't know enough about what is going on here.

I want the client to be able to continue using the web application without everything blocking.  Should my content type be different, or my parameters on the Mvc side?  I'm hoping this will get sent in chunks.

Even if my approach is correct, can someone enlighten me a little on what is happening here behind the scenes?  I've been seeing some posts that use a content type with "multipart" in it?  What is that, and should I be using it here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the request is sent asynchronously (which is the default setting) with jQuery it should not block the client.

Regarding the "multipart" question, that most likely refers to the form content type "multipart/form-data"

> The content type "multipart/form-data" should be used for submitting forms that contain files, non-ASCII data, and binary data.

source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Since you're sending base64 content, which is neither a file, "non-ASCII data" or binary you should be ok.